# subset all the data from another dataset

Tags: r

I wish to keep all the data from `dts1` that I have their transaction ID in `dts2`
This is my data:

```
dts1 <- data.frame (id = c(1,2,3,4,1,1), transactionID =c (10,22,47,15,13,NA))

dts2 <- data.frame ( transactionID = c(10,9,20,22))
```

In `dts1` I have transaction ID 10 that belongs to id 1 and transaction 22 that belongs to ID 2. **So, I wish to keep all the data from Id 1 and id 2 and delete data about the other ids**: My ideal output will be:

```
  id transactionID
  1            10
  2            22
  1            13
  1            NA
```

This one doesn't keep all the information about ids

```
dts3  <- dts1 [dts1$transactionID %in%  dts2$transactionID,]
```

Comment: 13 isn't in the dts2

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. 13 belongs to ID 1, because I have one of the transaction ID  of ID 1 in dts2 which is 10, I wish to keep all the data from ID 1. Not too sure if it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps:

first you get the id for which you have a transaction in dts2 like this:

```
dts1 [dts1$transactionID %in%  dts2$transactionID ,1]
[1] 1 2
```

Then you get the transaction tha have these ids:

```
dts1[dts1$id %in% dts1[dts1$transactionID %in% dts2$transactionID ,1],]
  id transactionID
1  1            10
2  2            22
5  1            13
6  1            NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Double merge:

```
merge(merge(dts1,dts2)["id"], dts1)
#  id transactionID
#1  1            10
#2  1            13
#3  1            NA
#4  2            22
```